# Better Heatmap Visualization using R

Tags: r

I am trying to use heaptmap visualization for my matrix that has 50 rows and 100 columns. I want to improve my heatmap by adding some additional features. The diagram is as follows:

[image]

```
heatmap.2(matrix,Rowv = NA,main = "Health Inverstments per DRG StateWise",xlab = "DRG Definition",
+           ylab = "States",Colv = NA,scale = "column", col = coul1, key = FALSE,
+           margins = c(5,5))
```

I would like to remove the lines and make the box more visible.

Comment: For me this first fails with `could not find function "heatmap.2"`. Once I searched on CRAN and found that it might be from the `gplots` package, I tried again and it failed with `'x' must be a numeric matrix`, likely because my `matrix` is a *function*, whereas I'm guessing that yours is something else. Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or created randomly including `set.seed(1)`). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: The below response helped me in removing the lines. I would like to know how to change the row values from right to left in heatmap using r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gplots/versions/3.0.1/topics/heatmap.2

remove lines with `, trace="none" )`

Comment: Usually link only answers are left as comments

Comment: The above response helped me in removing the lines. I would like to know how to change the row values from right to left in heatmap using r?